# Как выбрать <label> при нажатии на кнопку в js

Tags: javascript, button, label

Есть задача, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку

```
<button onclick="lok()">Кнопка</button>
```

Исполнялся js, который выберет указанный label, например:

```
<label for="radio_123">50 р.</label>
```

Каким образом это сделать и вообще возможно ли это?

Нужно чтобы это работало внутри функции:

```
<script>
function lok() {
/*здесь должен сработать выбор label*/
const t1 = Number(document.getElementById("ya1").innerHTML);  /*далее из ячейки забираются данные*/
document.getElementById("ya2").innerHTML = t1; /*и эти данные выводятся в другой ячейке*/
  }
</script>
```

Возможно вопрос задан не совсем на языке js, очень плохо знаком с языком, поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

решение оказалось простое, просто добавить класс, например "kl1" и

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("kl1");
elems[0].click();
```